# Lynx - how to delay download process before dump website's content

Tags: bash, shell, curl, chromium, lynx

I want to save whole content of this specific website using **lynx**

http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/perf/dashboard/ui/changelog.html?url=%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc&range=41818%3A40345&mode=html

I used these commands

```
webpage="http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/perf/dashboard/ui/changelog.html?url=%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc&range=41818%3A40345&mode=html"

lynx -crawl -dump  $webpage > output
```

My output was only like this:

```
SVN path: ____________________ SVN revision range: ____________________
```

When it was expected to have all information about bugs and comments.

In the URL, it included  "/trunk/src" and "41818:40345" values which should be put in to **SVN path** and **SVN revision range** and then submit it to get content but it didn't.

Question: Do you have any idea to "tell" lynx to wait a bit while the website is rendering its content until complete?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I found that lynx only considers this "changelog.html" because of the symbol "?".

Comment: So you've changed the double-quotes to single-quotes in `webpage=...` and it works, right?

Comment: @janSpurny: changing the quotes will make zipall difference in this case. Why do you think it would fix the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the webpage is being built by a javascript function. Such pages can be tricky to download with tools like lynx (or curl, which IMHO is better at the basic download problem). In order to download the contents you see on that page, you'd need to first load the javascript files needed by the page, and then execute the javascript "as though you were a browser". That javascript will proceed to request some data, which turns out to be XML, and then builds HTML from that data.

Note that the "website" doesn't render its data. Your browser renders the data. Or, to be more accurate, your browser is expected to render it but lynx won't because it doesn't do javascript.

So you have a couple of options. You could try to find a scriptable javascript-aware browser (iirc `links` does javascript, but I don't know offhand how to script it to do what you want.)

Or you can cheat. By using Chrom{e,ium}'s "developer" tools, you can see what URL is being requested by the javascript. It turns out, in this case, to be

```
http://build.chromium.org/cgi-bin/svn-log?url=http://src.chromium.org/svn//trunk/src&range=41818:40345
```

so you could get it with `curl` as follows

```
curl -G \
     -d url=http://src.chromium.org/svn//trunk/src \
     -d range=41818:40345 \
     http://build.chromium.org/cgi-bin/svn-log \
     > 41818-40345.xml
```

That XML data is in a pretty straightforward (i.e. apparently easy to reverse-engineer) format. And then you could use a simple scriptable xml tool like [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) (or any XSLT tool) to take the xml apart and reformat as you wish. With luck, you might even find some documentation (or a DTD) somewhere for the xml.

At least, that's how I would proceed.

Comment: +1 , thanks a lot. with this code, I got a nice xml file which contains whole information I need. But there is another problem when I need to collect those SVN revision logs for 1 year calendar time. One range revision 41818:40345 file was around 41K lines. The entire logs will have millions lines and it's not easy to reformat it. In the other hands, I need to change my code for reading plain text to XML files. I am searching for the way which is similar as ur suggestions but the output is plain text.

Comment: @LinhLino: perhaps the `svn-log` cgi is capable of producing output in other formats than XML, but I somehow doubt it. I'll reiterate my suggestion that you use a tool like xmlstarlet to reformat it. (I edited a link into my answer.) Or use an XML library in your processing code. Good luck.

Comment: You are right, lynx doesn't implement javascript, I've tried many ways to make it work but not succeeded. So XML is still the best option so far. Yes, I tried xmlstarlet before I found another way to reformat XML using command:
apt-get install tidy
cat ugly.xml | tidy -utf8 -xml -w 255 -i -c -q -asxml > pretty.xml
Source: http://www.qualitybrain.com/?p=37
Again, Thank you for your help.